# How can I run a method every day in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want change my database everyday automatically without sending a request.

Comment: consider using gems like [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: I am trying with delayed job. Thank you @shivam

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), it is very easy to use.

For example:

```
every 1.day, :at => '12pm' do
  rake "change_database_task"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally the realm of [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

You can set up a job to run a certain script on your server and it will work. Alternatively, many of the cloud environment providers (EG [Heroku](http://heroku.com)) have plugins such as the [`Heroku Scheduler`](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to handle the functionality.

An important factor to note about `Delayed Job` is that it uses external functionality to interface with the OS -- [Running Jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v4.0.6#running-jobs)

Thus, before you run to Delayed Job or Whenever, you need to be clear on what your hosting environment can handle. A great resource is the [RailsCast about DelayedJob](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job):

[image]